# Is there a nice finite sum expression for $\frac{x^{2n}(1-x)^{2n}}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: integration, polynomials

I am currently investigating the integral $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n}(1-x)^{2n}}{1+x^2}dx$$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. which seems to be a generator for rational approximations of $\pi$ or $\ln 2$ depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

But to investigate the rational component, I need to find an explicit sum for the integrand. The numerator is easily expressed as a sum with binomial coefficients, but the denominator is problematic. Currently, I cannot see a way of doing this as polynomial long division seems impractical here.

Is there anything I can do to get a finite sum for the integrand that I can integrate term-by-term?

Comment: What do you know about $n$?

Comment: I have added that $n$ is a natural number. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, yes I see!!

Comment: Maybe try the substitutution $x=\frac{u+1}{2}$

Comment: @MrYouMath What did you want me to do with this substitution? I end up with $$\frac{1}{2^{4n-1}}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\left ( 1-u^2 \right )^{2n}}{u^2+2u+5}$$which does not seem much better.

Comment: It is possible to write the integral as an hypergeometric function. But I don't know if it can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I_m = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{m}}{1+x^2}dx$. We then have
$$I_{m+1} + I_{m-1} = \int_0^1 x^{m-1}dx = \dfrac1{m}$$
We have $I_0 = \dfrac{\pi}4$ and $I_1 = \dfrac{\ln(2)}2$.
Hence, we have
\begin{align}
I_m & = \dfrac1{m-1} - \dfrac1{m-3} + \dfrac1{m-5} - \dfrac1{m-7} \pm \cdots +(-1)^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} I_{m\%2}\\
& = (-1)^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} I_{m\%2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2 \rfloor} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{m-2k+1}
\end{align}
Your integral is
$$I_n = \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{2n}(1-x)^{2n}}{1+x^2}dx = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k\dbinom{2n}k \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{2n+k}}{1+x^2}dx = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k\dbinom{2n}k I_{2n+k}$$
From this is where you obtain your $\pi/4$ and $\ln(2)/2$

Answer (score 3):

In the numerator, substituting $x=i$ and $x=-i$ (roots of $x^2+1=0$)  give $(i+1)^{2n}$ and $(1-i)^{2n}$ respectively. Since a higher order polynomial divided by a quadratic function would remain a linear function at most, denote that by $L(x)$, then we know:

$$L(i)=ai+b=(i+1)^{2n}=(\sqrt 2)^{2n}e^{\frac{i\pi n}2}$$

$$L(-i)=-ai+b=(1-i)^{2n}=(\sqrt 2)^{2n}e^{-\frac{i\pi n}2}$$

Solving it:

$a=2^n \sin({\frac{\pi n}2})$

$b=2^n \cos(\frac{\pi n}2)$

---

We first find the integral of $\frac{L(x)}{1+x^2}$

$$2^n \int_0^1 \frac{ \sin(\frac{\pi n}2)x+\cos(\frac{\pi n}2)}{1+x^2}dx$$

Let $\tan \theta =x$

$$=2^n \int_0^{\pi/4} \left(\sin(\frac{\pi n}2)\tan \theta + \cos(\frac{\pi n}2) \right)d\theta$$

Using $(\ln|\sec \theta |)'=\tan \theta$,

$$=2^{n-1} ( \ln 2 \sin(\frac{\pi n}2) +\frac{\pi}2 \cos(\frac{\pi n}2) )$$

---

Now we need to expand it to find the quotient, first rewrite it as

$$(1+x^2)^{2n-1} * \left(\frac{x-x^2}{x^2+1}\right)^{2n}=(1+x^2)^{2n-1}\left( \frac{x+1}{x^2+1}-1\right)^{2n}$$

$$=(1+x^2)^{2n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k (-1)^k \left(\frac {x+1}{x^2+1}\right)^{2n-k}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k (-1)^k (x+1)^{2n-k} (x^2+1)^{k-1}$$

The $k=0$ term matches with our remainder in the beginning, so the quotient (which would be a polynomial) is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\binom{2n}k (-1)^k (x+1)^{2n-k} (x^2+1)^{k-1}$$

Expanding the expansion:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left[ \binom{2n}k (-1)^k \left(\sum_{j=0}^{2n-k} \binom{2n-k}j x^j \right) \left(\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}l x^{2l}\right)\right]$$

Merging the product of sums into one:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left[ \binom{2n}k (-1)^k \sum_{j=0}^{2n-k} \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \binom{2n-k}j \binom{k-1}l x^{j+2l} \right]$$

Finally integrating:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\binom{2n}k (-1)^{2n-k} \left[\sum_{j=0}^{2n-k} \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \binom{2n-k}j \binom{k-1}l \int_0^1x^{j+2l} dx\right]$$

Answer:

> > $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left[\binom{2n}k (-1)^{2n-k} \sum_{j=0}^{2n-k} \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \left(\binom{2n-k}j \binom{k-1}l \frac 1{j+2l+1}\right) \right]+ 2^{n-1}( \sin(\frac{\pi n}2) \ln2 +\frac{\pi}2 \cos(\frac{\pi n}2) ) $$

Observe that the integral is very close to $0$ if we pick larger $n$ because the value of $x^{2n}(1-x)^{2n}$ between $[0,1]$ would be very small. With the above expression, it shows why we can get rational approximation of the $\ln 2$ and $\pi$ for odd or even $n$.

Answer (score 1):

---

For positive integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we define the terms $I_{n}$ via the integral representation,

$$I_{n}:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}\left(1-x\right)^{2n}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{1}$$

Begin by using the binomial theorem to expand the $\left(1-x\right)^{2n}$ factor as a polynomial in $x$ and integrating term by term to write $I_{n}$ as a linear combination of integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$, with $m$ taking nonnegative integer values. Then, we find

$$\begin{align}
I_{n}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}\left(1-x\right)^{2n}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}x^{k}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{\text{binomial expansion}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n+k}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{\text{integrate term by term}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\left(-1\right)^{2k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2\left(n+k\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\left(-1\right)^{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n+2k+1}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{\text{separate sum into even and odd terms}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2\left(n+k\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2\left(n+k\right)+1}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2\left(n+k\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^{n+k}}{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt{y}\right]}.\tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$

Recall that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the sum of a finite geometric series with $n$ terms is given by the familiar formula

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^{k}=
\begin{cases}
&\frac{1-z^{n}}{1-z};~~~\small{z\neq1},\\
&n;~~~\small{z=1}.\\
\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

The trick is rewrite the integral so that the integrands we want to expand have this form. We obtain,

$$\begin{align}
I_{n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2\left(n+k\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^{n+k}}{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+k}-\left[\left(-1\right)^{n+k}-x^{2\left(n+k\right)}\right]}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+k}-\left[\left(-1\right)^{n+k}-y^{n+k}\right]}{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\left(-1\right)^{n+k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^{2}}-\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\left(-1\right)^{n+k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y}\\
&~~~~~-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+k}-x^{2\left(n+k\right)}}{1+x^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+k}-y^{n+k}}{1+y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\left(-1\right)^{n+k}-\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\left(-1\right)^{n+k}\\
&~~~~~-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=0}^{n+k-1}\left(-1\right)^{n+k+j}x^{2j}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=0}^{n+k-1}\left(-1\right)^{n+k+j}y^{j}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\text{finite geometric sum formula}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\left(-1\right)^{k}-\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\left(-1\right)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\\
&~~~~~-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\sum_{j=0}^{n+k-1}\left(-1\right)^{n+k+j}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2j}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n+k-1}\left(-1\right)^{n+k+j}\int_{0}^{1}y^{j}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\text{integrate term by term}}\\
&=\left(-1\right)^{n}\left[\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\left(-1\right)^{k}-\frac12\ln{\left(2\right)}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}\sum_{j=0}^{n+k-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+k+j}}{2j+1}+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n+k-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+k+j}}{j+1}.\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

Since the question only asked for help getting past a certain step and not for an explicit final answer, for now I leave the rest to our fearless reader.

---